# Scheduled tasks won't start

Tags: cron

I am quite new to the world of Ubuntu (11.04 is my version), so please bear with me if I do not give all the necessary details to help you help me.

I constantly record radio streaming on the Internet using streamripper; it works wonderfully. To do so, I open Scheduled tasks (in Applications / System tools) and program streamripper to retrieve a certain streaming at a specific time for a certain length of time. Yesterday, Scheduled tasks bugged while I was adding a few more recording tasks; suddenly the list went blank, I could not click on "Add new task", the software was non-responsive. I shut it down (by clicking on the X). It would not open ever again. I rebooted, I even uninstalled and reinstalled Scheduled tasks: nothing worked.

All I could do was using crontab -e in Terminal (which works perfectly). I learned pretty fast how it worked, but the interface is not very user-friendly and would love to see the Scheduled tasks work again.

Has anyone any clue as to how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The bug disappeared by itself. It turned out that the scheduled task that caused the crash has just passed, so the "Scheduled tasks" software works again. I don't know what happened and I don't know how to solve the problem, but in my case, I just needed to wait for the fateful hour to pass and to see the graphic interface software to open by magic.

If someone knows what happened, I'd still be interested in understanding what went wrong and what I could have done to fix this problem while the software was frozen.